# How to Save Page Name and URL in React to Redux store at each Load

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Below code updates, the pageName and pageURL in my Redux Store for the user and I get that updated as a user browses around the react app.

```
const { match } = this.props;
if(match.params.type) {
  this.props.pageURL(match.url);
  this.props.pageName((match.params.type).replace(/-/g, " "));
}
```

If I put this code inside `render() {` method, everything works fine but I get this below error:

```
Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.
```

If I put it between class definition and render

```
class Skeleton extends Component {  
  render () {
```

It doesn't work, page name and URL in store stays old even when user navigates around.

Below I am showing how I set up Props, so I have App.js with this code:

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Fragment>
           <Route exact path="/" component={Skeleton} />  
           <Route path="/:type" component={Skeleton} />
      </Fragment>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
```

It directs user to Skeleton in any case with props in match so then I can figure out if user is on homepage `/` or some other ie `/Daily`, then on Skeleton I loads parts of the page and also save which page user attempted to go to. This page name and url saved to redux store so all components know which page user is trying to visit.

Full code

```
// 
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';

// Parts of the page
import Sidebar from './Skeleton/Sidebar';
import Content from './Skeleton/Content';
import TopBar from './Skeleton/TopBar';

// Redux
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { pageName, pageURL } from './../redux/actions';

class Skeleton extends Component {  
  render () { 
    const { match } = this.props;
    if(match.params.type) {
      this.props.pageURL(match.url);
      this.props.pageName((match.params.type).replace(/-/g, " "));
    }

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <CssBaseline />
        <TopBar />
        <Sidebar /> 
        <Content />
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    pageURL,
    pageName
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    pageName: Name => dispatch(pageName(Name)),
    pageURL: URL => dispatch(pageURL(URL)),
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) (Skeleton);
```

Comment: can you show us the code for pageURL and pageName props? also why are these function passed as prop instead of being a method inside this Component?

Comment: @Lelouch thank you, I just updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as the error says, you arent supposed to update state during render, the way to achieve this is check for your state/prop change before invoking your function to avoid render infinite loop. Try this:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  const {
    match: { url, params },
    pageName,
    pageUrl
  } = this.props

  // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props)
  if (url !== prevProps.match.url) {
    pageUrl(url)
    pageName((params.type).replace(/-/g, " "));
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  const {
    match: { url, params },
    pageName,
    pageUrl
  } = this.props

  pageUrl(url)
  pageName((params.type).replace(/-/g, " "));
}
```

Comment: basically, what's happening here is that whenever props.match.url changes, the pageUrl and pageName is called to update your redux store

Comment: I get marks under the match giving match is not defined.

Comment: Awesome I got it working with your direction, I'll send the code in the next

Comment: `  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const {
      match,
      pageName,
      pageURL
    } = this.props
  
    // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props)
    if (match.url !== prevProps.match.url) {
      pageURL(match.url);
      pageName((match.params.type).replace(/-/g, " "));
    }
  }`

Comment: actually this is not working for a scenario if user goes to directly to a page.

Comment: If I directly go to a sub page on first load, page name and URL ends up being empty. After that sure if I select an app from the dropdown and load another page it loads fine...

Comment: Okay so in regular cases it's a good idea to compare previous and next value. In this case I removed that if `if (url !== prevProps.match.url) {` comparison and now even when I load the app first time, I see whichever page I load to appear in the name properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try dispatching outside render. calls with side effects should only be called from componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate or in any other method that is called as a result of user interaction. Never inside render, componentWillMount or componentWillUpdate.

UPDATED:

Modify the component like this:

```
// 
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';

// Parts of the page
import Sidebar from './Skeleton/Sidebar';
import Content from './Skeleton/Content';
import TopBar from './Skeleton/TopBar';

// Redux
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { pageName, pageURL } from './../redux/actions';

class Skeleton extends Component {  

componentDidMount() {
    const { match } = this.props;
        if(match.params.type) {
          this.props.pageURL(match.url);
          this.props.pageName((match.params.type).replace(/-/g, " "));
        }
    }

  render () { 


    return (
      <Fragment>
        <CssBaseline />
        <TopBar />
        <Sidebar /> 
        <Content />
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    pageURL,
    pageName
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    pageName: Name => dispatch(pageName(Name)),
    pageURL: URL => dispatch(pageURL(URL)),
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) (Skeleton);
```

There are one very important thing to remember: when you dispatch your call, Redux modifies the component properties, which is illegal from the render() method.

All calls that do that must be from callbacks (like onClick, etc.) or from componentDidUpdate or componentDidMount. Never from componentWillUpdate or componentWillMount.

Once the call is made from componentDidMount, properties will have updated from Redux and a call to render() aill automatically be triggered. From there, access the new property values from your map.

Remember that each time a property or state is changed, React automatically triggers a render() and then a call to componentDidUpdate(). Because of this, any call in componentDidUpdate that updates the state or property (via Redux), a check must be made prior to avoid infinite loops.

Comment: I tried all of those lifecycle hooks you mentioned, none works properly.

Comment: Are you still getting the same error message? Would you care posting the whole component code?

Comment: sure just added.

Comment: See my modified answer.

Comment: Do you get the error message from your original post? If this is fixed, then your initial problem is fixed. If your page and url do not show expected values, it is a different problem. Create another post describing the new problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191337/discussion-between-user2343647-and-extelliqent).

Comment: thank you, I figured it out partially from your code and partially Lelouch's. I also tested it works like this. I'll share it now.

Comment: I shared it under @lelouch's answer.